# XSLT 1.0: help! can't remove element

Tags: xslt

just started with xslt   
need to remove element when it comes empty 
what am i doing wrong?
plz help

here comes some generated code with my attempt to solve the problem

my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" .....>     
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
        xalan:indent-amount="2" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!--
        The rule represents a custom mapping: "IdSelectFromDate" to
        "IdSelectFromDate".
    -->
    <xsl:template name="IdSelectFromDateToIdSelectFromDate">
        <xsl:param name="IdSelectFromDate" />
        <!-- ADD CUSTOM CODE HERE. -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$IdSelectFromDate = ''">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="IdSelectFromDate" />
                </xsl:copy>             
            </xsl:when>     
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="IdSelectFromDate" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="IdSelectFromDate" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body xmlns:httpsca="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/http/sca/6.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="foo.xsd">
  <tns:getRealEstateObjects>
    <RequestElement>         
      <IdNumnet>IdNumnet</IdNumnet>
      <IdSelectFromDate xsi:nil="true"/>
    </RequestElement>
  </tns:getRealEstateObjects>
</body>
```

desired output:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <body xmlns:httpsca="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/http/sca/6.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="foo.xsd">
      <tns:getRealEstateObjects>
        <RequestElement>         
          <IdNumnet>IdNumnet</IdNumnet>

        </RequestElement>
      </tns:getRealEstateObjects>
    </body>
```

Comment: p.s. remove element only when empty - otherwise preserve

Comment: Your input XML is not namespace-well-formed (it uses the `tns` prefix which has not been bound to a namespace URI) so XSLT is going to have trouble with it.

Comment: the above xslt code is called from:        ' <xsl:if test="$body/IdSelectFromDate">
          <IdSelectFromDate>
            <!-- variables for custom code -->
            <xsl:variable name="IdSelectFromDate" select="$body//IdSelectFromDate"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="IdSelectFromDateToIdSelectFromDate">
              <xsl:with-param name="IdSelectFromDate" select="$IdSelectFromDate"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </IdSelectFromDate>
        </xsl:if>'

Comment: there is no problem with tns inside my environment - i just cut tns info to focus on the problem

Comment: It's fine to trim your examples down when posting to SO (indeed it's encouraged), but the code and data you post needs to be complete enough for other people to run it, which this isn't without an `xmlns:tns="something"`.

Comment: How is this different from this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109093/xslt-1-0-remove-element-only-if-it-is-empty

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach to use here is an identity template with a template to match the part you want to remove:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="IdSelectFromDate[. = '']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<body xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="foo.xsd" 
      xmlns:httpsca="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/http/sca/6.1.0" 
      xmlns:tns="..." 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns:getRealEstateObjects>
    <RequestElement>
      <IdNumnet>IdNumnet</IdNumnet>
    </RequestElement>
  </tns:getRealEstateObjects>
</body>
```